# Can I use the file buffer or stream as input for fluent-ffmpeg? I am trying to avoid saving the video locally to get its path before removing

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg, nestjs, fluent-ffmpeg

I am receiving the file via an api, I was trying to process the file.buffer as input for FFmpeg but it did not work, I had to save the video locally first and then process the path and remove the saved video later on.
I don't want to believe that there is no other way to solve this and I have been looking for solutions and workarounds but it was all about ffmpeg input as a path.

I would love to find a solution using fluent-ffmpeg because it has some other great features, but I won't mind any suggestions for compressing the video using any different approaches if it's more efficient

Again my code below works fine but I have to save the video and then remove it I am hoping for a more efficient solution:

```
  fs.writeFileSync('temp.mp4', file.buffer);

    // Resize the temporary file using ffmpeg
    ffmpeg('temp.mp4') // here I tried pass file.buffer as readable stream,it receives paths only 
      .format('mp4')
      .size('50%')
      .save('resized.mp4')
      .on('end', async () => {
        // Upload the resized file to Firebase
        const resizedFileStream = bucket.file(`video/${uniqueId}`).createWriteStream();
        fs.createReadStream('resized.mp4').pipe(resizedFileStream);

        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
          resizedFileStream
            .on('finish', () => {
              // Remove the local files after they have been uploaded
              fs.unlinkSync('temp.mp4');
              fs.unlinkSync('resized.mp4');
              resolve();
            })
            .on('error', reject);
        });

        // Get the URL of the uploaded resized version
        const resizedFile = bucket.file(`video/${uniqueId}`);
        const url = await resizedFile.getSignedUrl({
          action: 'read',
          expires: '03-17-2025', // Change this to a reasonable expiration date
        });

        console.log('Resized file uploaded successfully.');
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
      });
```